# Does Impala support user-defined functions written in Impala SQL (not C++ or Java)?

Tags: hadoop, impala

Impala does support [UDFs written in C++ or Java](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/latest/topics/impala_udf.html), but I have a simple formula composed of built-in function calls. I need to use many times in my code and I don't want to repeat it.

Is anything similar to the pseudo-code below supported?

```
-- UDF definition
CREATE FUNCTION get_date_string (datetime p_value)
AS
  RETURN year(p_value)*10000 + month(p_value)*100 + day(p_value) ;

-- UDF call
SELECT get_date_string(CreatedOn)
FROM Posts ;
```

**Update:**
Hive supports such UDFs - they are called [macros](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2655) but I found very little information about this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Impala does not yet have support for stored procedures or "macros".

Comment: Can you provide any reference? A Jira task showing it is planned or a roadmap document that mentions this feature?

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have this feature on our public roadmap and there is no JIRA, but feel free to file an IMPALA JIRA here: https://issues.cloudera.org